# XAMPP PHP MIME type wrong for .zip

Tags: php, mime

I'm using XAMPP 1.7.7 on Windows XP and doing a upload of a .zip file.

```
$_FILES shows:
array(1) {
["P24_File"]=>
array(5) {
["name"]=>
string(12) "File.zip"
["type"]=>
string(15) "unknown/unknown"
["tmp_name"]=>
string(22) "...\php1B.tmp"
["error"]=>
int(0)
["size"]=>
int(12927)
}
}
```

Surprisingly finfo_file() shows "application/zip; charset=binary"...

What's wrong with $_FILES?

Comment: It a permission problem.

Comment: The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

Answer (score 0):

This information is supplied by the *browser*, it has nothing to do with the server. Probably the client's computer doesn't have a ZIP utility installed, or the browser is not aware of the ZIP file type for some other reason.

Because it can be faked (or incorrect, as in your example), you can't trust that info anyway.

`finfo_file()` is the source to trust here.